# How can i calculate the right coordinates?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, coordinates

I need help. I have a Picturebox and would now like to calculate given coordinates on the picture and then play them in the label. How can I do that best?

As seen in the picture.
If you then click on the image on it, then the data is entered in a list box.

Thank you for your help.

My Picture here: https://prnt.sc/puxyu6

Comment: What have you tried? where do you have a problem?

Comment: Is this a game of some sort? Or something that requires similar heavy drawing? Also which picture box. Aka, what is your display technolgoy: WinForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net, other?

Comment: On Combobox it change the Picture on the pictures are on the site the Coords now i need to know how can i calc this the specific coord i dont want the Form coords of this windows only the cord in the picture on the site you can see the coords.

https://prnt.sc/puy73k

Comment: I repeat: What is your display technolgoy: WinForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net, other? They all have a different picture box and thus need a different solution.

Comment: Oh sorry yes i use the WPF

Answer (score 0):

In WPF this particular might for once be the hardest. WPF/UWP is designed for the MVVM, and I do not know anyone but beginners that programm outside of MVVM. And I can not think of way to do this with MVVM.

PictureBox is also the WinForms Element. [The WPF equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/windows-forms-controls-and-equivalent-wpf-controls) is called [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image).

Navigation aids like this are not a trivial thing. One reason there are so few of it. But it comes down to few step process:

1. Get the x and y pixel coordinates that was clicked, also in relation to that the overall display size of the Image. Usually the MouseClick Event would be the tool for that, but I can not find it. MouseDown or LeftMouseDown are the closest events.
2. If the entire image was shown with no zooming or cropping, it is now just simple math. If it was 20% of the X axis and 21% of the Y axis, it is pretty easy to figure out where 20% of X and 21 of Y is on the SourceImage.
3. If there was any zoom or crop, this has to be taken into account, otherwise it is 2.
4. Equate the Image Pixel position with the coordinates you know for it.

Part 1 would look like this and needs to be registered with the MouseDown or LeftMouseDown Event of the Image:

```
private void ContentControl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  //Unpack the sender
  Image source = (Image)Sender;

  //Get the click point
  Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(source);

  //There is more then 1 height Property in WPF. 
  //The Actuall one is what you are looking for
  //Unfortunately you get doubles for this and int for the other. Consider general advise regarding double math
  double ElementHeight = source.ActualHeight;
  double ElementWidth = source.ActualWidth;

  //Do what you need to find the relative position

  //Part 2
}
```

Hopefully someone else can give you a better answer.